# Is dojo 1.3 and 1.4 compatible with IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo

Examples found in the dojo documentation won't load in IE.

Such as: http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Calendar

I've tried it in IE7, IE8, and quirks mode.

Is this problem merely in how they've implemented their documentation? Or are the new dojo frameworks incompatible with IE?

Comment: It is likely the website.  All dojo 1.4 is compatible IE6-IE8 as per the http://docs.dojocampus.org/releasenotes/1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo is compatible with IE, but the manner in which the dojo.js file is being loaded is causing errors on the documentation pages. Many examples have the `<script>` blocks appearing outside of the `<head>` or `<body>` elements which is causing IE to throw a fit (and reasonably so). Dojo needs to clean up their demos. Documentation is definitely a work in progress. I recommend you use FireFox to view the demos on dojocampus.org.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error that occurs when loading the page:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Mon, 14 Dec 2009 19:15:40 UTC

Message: 'this.iframe.contentDocument' is null or not an object
Line: 16
Char: 239089
Code: 0
URI: http://docs.dojocampus.org/moin_static185/js/dojo/trunk/docs/layer.js

I'm guessing this just means that their documentation just doesn't work in IE, so the framework itself may or may not work in IE. But if they can't even make their docs work in IE, that doesn't leave me very hopeful.

Comment: You should edit your original question, not "not" answer your original question.